# Find subsequence ocurrence in multiple strings

Tags: string, algorithm, subsequence

Given one string say `S` of length `m`  and a set of other strings **`R`** all with lengths equal or bigger than `m`. Find the strings in the set that have `S` as a subsequence.

So, if `S` is `blr` and the set of strings is:

```
bangalore
booleer
bamboo
```

It should return the first two strings.

I'm aware that I can find if a string `S` of length `m` is a subsecuence of other string `T` of length `n`  in time complexity O(n+m). So I know I could just do this algorithm for each element in the set, but that would be a time complexity of O(k*(n+m)), being `k` the size of the set (and assuming all the strings have the same length). This makes me wonder if there's some kind of preprocessing that helps me solve this problem with multiple strings.

So, is there any preprocessing or structure I can use to solve this problem? 
What's the best time complexity I can achieve?
Are there any other approachs to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

For tow string ch and s if you want to find if ch is in the set that have S as a subsequence, the algorithm will have the complexity O(n)

```
 public  bool function(string ch, string s)
        {
            if (ch.Length < s.Length)
                return false;

            int j = 0;
            for (int i = 0; i < ch.Length; i++)
            {
                if (ch[i] == s[j])
                {
                    j++;
                    if (s.Length == j)
                    {
                        return true;
                    }
                }
            }
            return false;
        }
```

After thatyou have to apply it for all your string in R

Answer (score 0):

I haven't got a code implementation, but I did manage to find a 1984 paper ["Computing a longest common subsequence for a set of strings"](https://ir.nctu.edu.tw/bitstream/11536/4866/1/A1984SR65400005.pdf), by W. J. Hsu and M. W. Du.

Their conclusion is that by doing O(L) preprocessing time (where L is the aggregate length of all the strings in the set), it is possible to perform each search in O(P), where P is the number of times the needle appears in the haystacks.